# How to properly release SoundPool objects?

Tags: java, android, button, release, soundpool

The following code plays a random sound. I'm trying to release it since I no longer need the button to play anything else, but when I run the application the button will not play any sound at all.

```
public class actibida extends AppCompatActivity {
SoundPool soundPool;
Button button;
boolean loaded = false;

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_actibida);

    soundPool = new SoundPool(1, AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, 0);
    soundPool.setOnLoadCompleteListener(new SoundPool.OnLoadCompleteListener() {
        @Override
        public void onLoadComplete(SoundPool soundPool, int sampleId, int status) {
            loaded = true;
        }
    });

    //I have a total of four sounds
    final int[] sound = new int[4];
    sound[0] = soundPool.load(actibida.this, R.raw.el, 1);
    sound[1] = soundPool.load(actibida.this, R.raw.guau, 1);
    sound[2] = soundPool.load(actibida.this, R.raw.miau, 1);
    sound[3] = soundPool.load(actibida.this, R.raw.quack, 1);

    final Random r = new Random();

    button = (Button) this.findViewById(R.id.button);
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View button) {

            final Random r = new Random();
            int Low = 0;
            int High = 3;
            int rndm = r.nextInt(High - Low) + Low;
            soundPool.play(sound[r.nextInt(4)], 1.0f, 1.0f, 0, 0, 1.0f);


        }

    });
    soundPool.release();
        }
}
```

Can somebody please educate me on how to properly call .release()?

P.S. If I'm going to play some other sounds in the app, should I use a different SoundPool class? Or should I just release it and load it again? The thing is I'm not even able to release in the first place, so I can't tell.

Answer (score 1):

You're releasing the SoundPool before the sound finishes playing.  In fact, you're releasing it the moment playback starts.  The play() method doesn't wait for sounds to finish - the playback is asynchronous.  Also, there isn't a way to find out when the playback finishes.

If you're going to play from the same pool of sounds in the future, you can simply make the SoundPool some sort of singleton or store it in some place where it can be reused.

Comment: I edited the post so that anyone could check the rest of the code. I tried placing soundPool.release(); at the very end, but it still doesn't work. Were should I place it?

Comment: If you're not going to use it after the activity finishes, then release in onDestroy().